# find all permutations from a list of lists where outputs contain all, none, or any of the items in each list

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, combinatorics

I have any arbitrary number of lists with an arbitrary number of elements. I need to find the permutations such that each permutation contains all, any, or none of the elements from each list

```
l1 = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
l2 = ['big','small','medium']
l3 = ['fast','slow','stopped']

res = function([l1,l2,l3])

res = [(['red', 'blue', 'green'], ['big','small','medium'], ['fast','slow','stopped']),
 (['red', 'blue'], ['big','small','medium'], ['fast','slow','stopped']),
      ([],[],['fast'])]
```

I looked any cartesian products and itertools but my problem appears to be distinctly different because I need all, any, or none rather than just every combination of a fixed set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess here's my hacky solution.

```
products = []
for r in range(len(l1)+1):
    perm = list(itertools.combinations(l1, r))
    for r2 in range(len(l2)+1):
        perm2 = list(itertools.combinations(l2, r2)) 
        for r3 in range(len(l3)+1):
            perm3 = list(itertools.combinations(l3, r3))
            for p in perm:
                for p2 in perm2:
                    for p3 in perm3:
                        products.append((p,p2,p3))
```